# Trying to bake feather detail onto a bird but result is pure Chaos, Help

Tags: normals, baking, normal-map

As stated, I am baking feathers onto a bird's body but the result when baked looks like pure chaos.

[image]

I thought this would work out because it worked great on the wing. The feathers baked great to the 2d plane. I attempted to replicate this problem by using one face of a cube, and I noticed that the feathers bake straight through to the back.

[image]

I don't see where to correct this either and it may be part of the problem. I thought this would work but clearly I'm missing something or baking just doesn't work like how I thought it should. Any advice would be much appreciated. If yall need more specific info just ask. (hoping one of you can identify my error with just this)

[image]

Comment: Does the UVmap contains the whole mesh, or just a half of it with mirroring?

Comment: No mirroring here, and all the face normals have been recalculated. I tried baking with each feather its own object and joined as one mesh with same result. The problem is either with the body mesh or my baking method (which is just standard stuff, tho ive never tried baking with something as complex before)